# Array of arrays of different types of shapes

Tags: c++

I want to create a "3D console game" using RayCasting. To begin with, I needed a container with all the information about the world. First of all, I started with just two shapes, a rectangle and a circle. Actually, here's how I implemented them:

```
enum POINTS
{
    POINT_1,
    POINT_2
};

enum ASIXS
{
    ASIX_X,
    ASIX_Y,
};

class Point
{
private:
    double properties[2];

public:
    Point()
    {
        properties[ASIX_X] = 0;
        properties[ASIX_Y] = 0;
    }

    Point(double x, double y)
    {
        properties[ASIX_X] = x;
        properties[ASIX_Y] = y;
    }

    double& operator[] (int index)
    {
        return properties[index];
    }
};

class Rectangle
{
private:
    Point base[2];

public:
    //Points getter
    Point& operator[](int index)
    {
        return base[index];
    }
};

class Circle
{
private:
    Point center;
    double radius = 0;

public:
    Point& getCenter()
    {
        return center;
    }

    double& getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }
};
```

Next, I need a generic container. Obviously this should be a pattern:

```
template<typename T>
class ObjectArr
{
protected:
    int qty;
    T* objs;

public:
    ObjectArr()
    {
        qty = 0;
        objs = nullptr;
    }

    ~ObjectArr()
    {
        delete[] objs;
    }
    
    void add()
    {
        T* temp = new T[++qty];
        for (int i = 0; i < qty - 1; i++)
            temp[i] = objs[i];
        delete[] objs;
        objs = temp;
    }

    T getObj(int index)
    {
        return objs[index];
    }
};
```

Here's what it will look like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ObjectArr<Rectangle> rect;
    rect.add();

    //rect.getObj(id)[point][asix]
    rect.getObj(0)[POINT_1][ASIX_X] = 5;
    cout << rect.getObj(0)[POINT_1][ASIX_X]; //Out 5

    ObjectArr<Circle> cir;
    cir.add();

    //cir.getObj(id).getCenter()[asix]//getRadius()
    cir.getObj(0).getCenter() = {0, 0};

    return 0;
}
```

And in the end, I would like one common container that would store ObjectArr<>. From the beginning I thought about polymorphism. Something like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Container
{
     //...
};

template<typename T>
class ObjectArr : public Container
{
     //...
};

int main()
{
    vector<Container*> test;

    test.push_back(new ObjectArr<Rectangle>);
    test.push_back(new ObjectArr<Circle>);

    test[0]->add();
     
     //...

     return 0;
}
```

But with this approach, the function T getObj(int index) cannot be used from such a container. And writing it as a virtual one will not work either because of the template. And I also don’t want to prescribe every possible shape, so that it would be easier to add new shapes. Wrote a class of a new figure and all. Tell me, please, how should I be and what should I do, maybe I need to completely change the approach?

Comment: As written, nothing prevents the user to call `test.push_back(new ObjectArr<Rectangle>);` twice, which would leave you with several `ObjectArr<>` for the same shape inside your vector. Is it intended ?

Comment: Usually, we tend to handle this pattern by using polymorphism the other way. An abstract base class `Shape` inherited by all actual shapes (`Point`, `Rectangle`, `Circle`, ...). And then we handle a collection of `Shape*` (or references, or smart pointers, ....), for example: `std::vector<Shape*>`. And so on. Not sure if it matches exactly your use-case though, we lack information about the actual goal you want to achieve in the end.